# passing array of data between fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass a `category[]` (Category is a model)structure between fragments .....

I am able to pass like `ArrayList<String>` using

```
fragment = new FrgAddItemInfo();
                        fragment.setArguments(mBundle);
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FrgAddItemInfo.class.getSimpleName());
                        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, FrgAddItemInfo.class.getSimpleName());
```

1. But I am not able to pass  `category[]`
2. How to resolve this

Comment: If you want to pass user defined model, then your model class have to implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try to create a constructor of the fragment and use it to pass objects between them.

In the fragment FrgAddItemInfo, Add following :

```
   /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param category Parameter 1.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FrgAddItemInfo.
     */
    public static FrgAddItemInfo newInstance(Category[] category) {
        FrgAddItemInfonewInstance fragment = new FrgAddItemInfonewInstance();
        fragment.setCategories(category);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setCategories(Category[] category) {
        mCategory = category;
    }
```

And use it as

```
    fragment = FrgAddItemInfo.newInstance(category);
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FrgAddItemInfo.class.getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, FrgAddItemInfo.class.getSimpleName());
```

Answer (score 3):

Your object Category must implement Parcelable

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

However as a workaround you can serialize your class to a json String using Google's Gson and sending as a String.

https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Bundle#putParcelableArray();` if `Category` implements parcelable

Or u can use some serialization to `byte[]` of to `String`(with JSON for example) in the other case.